# TypeScript Interface Undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this:

```
  public getFriends() : IUser[] {
    let friends: IUser[];
    friends[0].Id = "test";
    friends[0].Email = "asdasd";

    return friends;
  }
```

Could sound stupid, but why am I getting friends[0] undefined? What am I supposed to do if I don't have a class of type User in this case.

Comment: Only the type is declared for the field but not initialized. e.g. `let friends: IUser[] = []`.

Comment: you need to `push` into `friends`.

Comment: At no point are you creating the array, and much less an object in that array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this statement:

```
let friends: IUser[];
```

You are declaring `friends` and its type `IUser[]`, you aren't initializing it yet, so `friends`'s value is `undefined` at this point.

So, the first step is to initialize it:

```
let friends: IUser[] = [];
```

Now it **is** an array, you have to push some content into it. First you have to create a `IUser`:

```
// this is one (likely) way of creating a IUser instance, there may be others
let friend: IUser = {Id: "test", Email: "asdasd"};
```

And then add it to the array:

```
friends.push(friend);
```

---

So your final code would be:

```
public getFriends() : IUser[] {
    let friends: IUser[] = [];

    let friend: IUser = {Id: "test", Email: "asdasd"};
    friends.push(friend);

    return friends;
}
```